# Parameterized update in SQL(Microsoft Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to update the state capital from table STATES with a city from table CITIES.
I want both , the state name and city name to be parameterized.

have this code

```
UPDATE STATES
SET State_capital=DLookUp("ID","CITIES","City='Los Angeles'")
WHERE State_name=[Enter State Name:];
```

The problem is that the City name is not parameterized in DLookUp and Access does not accept this form of the update :

```
UPDATE STATES
SET State_capital=(SELECT ID FROM CITIES WHERE City=[Insert city here])
WHERE State_name=[Enter State Name:];
```

What is the solution?Thank you !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568461/is-it-possible-to-pass-parameters-programmatically-in-a-microsoft-access-update

Answer (score 3):

This query works for me in Access 2010:

```sql
PARAMETERS [Enter City name:] Text(255), [Enter State name:] Text(255);
UPDATE STATES SET 
State_capital=DLookup("ID","CITIES","City='" & Replace([Enter City name:],"'","''") & "'")
WHERE State_name=[Enter State name:]
```