# Getting data from tables and put it into a template

Tags: vba, ms-access, templates, ms-word, ms-access-2007

I'm sitting with a word template and I have to generate the template via Access 2007. I've the following code:

```
Public Function CH05_Generate()

Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim Doc As Word.Document
Dim WordPath As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim sql As String

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("Projektdata", dbOpenDynaset)


WordPath = "Where my word template is"

Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set Doc = WordApp.Documents.Add(WordPath)

With Doc

    .FormFields("PName").Result = [Projektnavn]
    .FormFields("text").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!Kommentar
    .FormFields("S3").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q1
    .FormFields("S4").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q2
    .FormFields("S5").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q3
    .FormFields("S6").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q4
    .FormFields("S7").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q5
    .FormFields("S8").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q6
    .FormFields("S9").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q7
    .FormFields("S10").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q8
    .FormFields("S11").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q9
    .FormFields("S12").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q10
    .FormFields("S13").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q11
    .FormFields("S14").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q12
    .FormFields("S15").CheckBox.Value = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q13
    .FormFields("S16").CheckBox.Value = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q14
    .FormFields("S17").CheckBox.Value = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q15
    .FormFields("S18").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q16
    .FormFields("S19").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q17
    .FormFields("S20").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q18        
End With

WordApp.visible = True
WordApp.Activate
WordApp.ActiveDocument.Protect wdAllowOnlyFormFields, True

End Function
```

What I need help with is to get "Projektnavn" from the table named "Projektdata", but I have no idea how to get the data from it. There are many "projektnavn", so maybe I should do some sort of lookup?
[image]
As you can see there they all have a sagsnr, maybe that helps?

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the recordset `rst` depends on how the query `Projektdata` is designed. If your query returns a single row, you can retreive the data by simply using the column name:

```
If Not rst.EOF Then
    .FormFields("PName").Result = rst("YOUR_COLUMN_NAME")
End If
```

The `If` statement is needed in case the query does not return any rows.

**EDIT**

I don't know how the query `Projektdata` is designed. In order to make it only return the correct row, you will have to modify it to accept a parameter to identify which row to return. You can pass a parameter for `sagsnr` if it is unique for each row. I've expanded the code sample and added some cleanup:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

Set db = CurrentDb()

Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("Projektdata")
qdf!plSagsnr = 1  'Add parameter value to only fetch data where sagsnr is 1
Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset

If Not rst.EOF Then
    Debug.Print rst("Field1")
End If

rst.Close
qdf.Close
db.Close

Set rst = Nothing
Set qdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: That works, but I didn't get the result I was looking for. I got the first "projektnavn" in the column, but I need the specific name. Maybe it should do some sort of lookup?

Comment: You will either have to design your query to only return the correct row or sort through all the rows in the `CH05_Generate` sub. I recommend making sure the query returns what you want, it is probably easier.

Comment: Could you maybe help me with it? I'm kinda lost here.

Comment: See edit. You have not shown the code for the query. You will have to modify it to accept a parameter for sagsnr and then select the correct row based on the parameter.

Comment: Also, see [this Q+A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16571156/1490783) for more information on queries and parameters.