# Run Time error 3061 Too Few parameters. Expected 6. Unable to update table from listbox

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

All,

I am running the below SQL and I keep getting error 3061. Thank you all for the wonderful help! I've been trying to teach myself and I am 10 days in and oh my I am in for a treat!

```
Private Sub b_Update_Click()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb

strSQL = "UPDATE Main" _
       & " SET t_Name = Me.txt_Name, t_Date = Me.txt_Date, t_ContactID = Me.txt_Contact, t_Score = Me.txt_Score, t_Comments = Me.txt_Comments" _
       & " WHERE RecordID = Me.lbl_RecordID.Caption"
       CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
```

Comment: You're passing in a literal string "Me.txt_Name" (etc etc) instead of the value itself.

Comment: These are textboxes should I add .value?

Comment: You need to build the actual values into the SQL string, so `strSQL = "UPDATE Main SET t_Name = '" & Me.txt_Name & "', t_Date...`

Comment: Be careful with that approach.  Instead use `parameterized queries` -- several examples on SO about it.  Here's one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568461/is-it-possible-to-pass-parameters-programmatically-in-a-microsoft-access-update

Comment: Thanks guys. Can I use the Text boxes as a parameter ?

Comment: I'm not sure why no one has mentioned this yet, but I believe you need to declare `strSQL` as a variable. Somewhere above the line that you use `strSQL` ; input the following `dim strSQL as String`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but, you can try somethink like that

if you knom the new value to insert in the database try with a syntax like this one

```
UPDATE table
SET Users.name = 'NewName',
    Users.address = 'MyNewAdresse'
WHERE Users.id_User = 10;
```

Now, if you want to use a form (php)
You have to use this

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["id_user" ])) {$id_user = $_REQUEST["id_user" ];}
else {$id_user = "" ;}
if(isset($_REQUEST["name" ])) {$name= $_REQUEST["name" ];}
else {$name = "" ;}
if(isset($_REQUEST["address" ])) {$address= $_REQUEST["adress" ];}
else {$adress= "" ;}
```

if you use mysql
     UPDATE table
        SET Users.name = '$name',
            Users.address = '$adress'
        WHERE Users.id_User = 10;

i don't know VBA but I will try to help you

Comment: Well I might have taken the wrong approach. I have a form and I put a listbox in it. When they hit search I use row source to display the values in the listbox. Well, I want to use a double click event to display the info in the form....

Comment: I prepared an example of form with a listbox with an example of how to retrieve data and I post

Comment: Wow. That would be great! Thank you!

Comment: I have a website you can help you   https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Update-data-by-using-a-query-f01eb7a3-a673-4edd-a425-f6769d2bb717

Comment: Some help for listbox with VBA  http://www.java2s.com/Code/VBA-Excel-Access-Word/Forms/Selecttheitemsprogrammatically.htm

Comment: Thank you everyone for the awesome advice. I honestly appreciate it !

Answer (score 0):

Going on from my comment, you first need to declare `strSQL` as a string variable. 
Where your error expects 6 values and access doesn't know what they are. This is because form objects need to be outside the quotations of the SQL query, otherwise (as in this case) it will think they are variables and obviously undefined. The 6 expected are the 5 form fields plus 'strSQL'.

```
Private Sub b_Update_Click()
Dim db As DAO.Database
dim strSQL as string
Set db = CurrentDb

strSQL = "UPDATE Main" & _
         " SET t_Name = '" & Me.txt_Name & "'," & _
         " t_Date =#" & Me.txt_Date & "#," & _
         " t_ContactID =" & Me.txt_Contact & "," & _
         " t_Score =" & Me.txt_Score & "," & _
         " t_Comments = '" & Me.txt_Comments & "'," & _
         " WHERE RecordID = '" & Me.lbl_RecordID.Caption & "';"

       CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
end sub
```

Note how I have used double quotes to put the form fields outside of the query string so access knows they aren't variables.
If your field is a string, it needs encapsulating in single quotes like so `'string'`. If you have a date field it needs encapsulating in number signs like so `#date#` and numbers/integers don't need encapsulating.

Look at the code I have done and you can see I have used these single quotes and number signs to encapsulate certain fields. I guessed based on the names of the fields like `ID`'s as numbers. I may have got some wrong so alter where applicable... Or comment and I will correct my answer.

Comment: This is great. Thank you so much for taking the time to break it down. I am getting a syntax error. The only fields that contain numbers is contact id & score. Also, t_Comments has multi lines would that cause an issue? Again, I appreciate what you are doing.

Comment: I'll have a look in to the syntax soon, I'm not sure whether the syntax error might be arising from. any syntax error code etc?  No I don't think multi line text fields can cause a problem if it is just a text field, maybe ensure characters are under 255?

Comment: Yeah they are under 255. I'll post the specific error.