# How to Add User Input Criterion to an Access Inner Joined Crosstab Query

Tags: ms-access, inner-join, user-input, crosstab

Prompting for user input parameters in an Access query is fairly straight forward.  Go to design view and under criteria, just put [Your Text:] -- and when the query runs the user is prompted for the field criteria.

Unfortunately when I try this with my Inner Joined Crosstab query I get the error:

> The Microsoft Access engine does not recognize the '[Your Text:]' as a
>   valid field name or expression.

I know the inner join crosstab still allows for criteria, as hardcorded criterion works.

To give you a better idea of what I'm looking at, here is the SQL code.

DOESN'T WORK:

```
SELECT *
FROM ([CrossTabQ1] 
INNER JOIN [CrossTabQ2] ON [CrossTabQ1].[Month] = [CrossTabQ2].[Month]) 
INNER JOIN [Query3] ON [CrossTabQ1].[Month] = [Query3].[Month]
WHERE ((([CrossTabQ1].[Month])= [Enter Month, in YYYY-MM Format:]))
ORDER BY [CrossTabQ1].[Month];
```

DOES WORK:

```
WHERE ((([CrossTabQ1].[Month])="2015-12"))
ORDER BY [CrossTabQ1].[Month];
```

Any tips regarding why I'm getting this error and how I can accept user input criterion would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
PARAMETERS Enter_Month Text ( 255 );
SELECT *
FROM ([CrossTabQ1] 
INNER JOIN [CrossTabQ2] ON [CrossTabQ1].[Month] = [CrossTabQ2].[Month]) 
INNER JOIN [Query3] ON [CrossTabQ1].[Month] = [Query3].[Month]
WHERE ((([CrossTabQ1].[Month])=[Enter_Month]))
ORDER BY [CrossTabQ1].[Month];
```

Comment: That gives me "Syntax error in query expression 'WHERE (((...remaining code'.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe PARAMETER's  name not acceptable, I update it to simple name as I see it in my query SQL view and test it in ms access 2010, see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16568461/4039286) maybe help.

Comment: This worked great, thank you @Fadi!  For those that might stumble into this issue and want to use spaces and special characters, just add brackets "[ ]" around Enter_Month in the Parameters line.  Ex. "PARAMETERS [Enter Month (YYYY-MM format)] Text (255); ... then WHERE... =[Enter Month (YYYY-MM format)].  All set!

Comment: @TMY, Thank You for these extra informations about `spaces and special characters`.