# How to substitute a variable into an OpenRecordSet query

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am almost there:

The variable **strCons** contains a number and I would like to add this to the SQL. When I do this like below, I get this run-time error:

> 3061 Too few parameters. Expected 1.

When I replace `strCons` with a number it works. Tried to find out why with no luck.

`Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Member.HomeEmail FROM Member INNER JOIN MemberRole ON Member.MemberID = MemberRole.MemberID WHERE (((MemberRole.AreaID)= strCons) AND ((MemberRole.RoleID)=1) AND ((MemberRole.FinishDate) Is Null)) ORDER BY Member.Surname")`

`strEmailTD = rs.Fields(0).Value
rs.Close`

Comment: You need to substitute the value of `strCons` into the query, not just its name; right now, it is just text that does not mean anything to the database. But then just substituting it is a bad idea because it will leave you vulnerable to SQL injection. So, you should use a parameterised query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to pass parameters programmatically in a Microsoft Access update query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568461/is-it-possible-to-pass-parameters-programmatically-in-a-microsoft-access-update)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Member.HomeEmail FROM Member INNER JOIN MemberRole ON Member.MemberID = MemberRole.MemberID WHERE (((MemberRole.AreaID)=" & strCons & ") AND ((MemberRole.RoleID)=1) AND ((MemberRole.FinishDate) Is Null)) ORDER BY Member.Surname")
```