# Replace parameter in SQL query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to replace Query1.Period parameter "May 2018" with "Jun 2018".

SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW Query1.Period, Query1.Portfolio_1
FROM Query1
WHERE (((Query1.Period)="May 2018"))
ORDER BY Query1.Portfolio_2, Query1.Department, Query1.Position_NO;
```

VBA code attempt:

```
Private Sub newChangePeriodCriteria_Click()
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim qdfOLD As String
Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Query1_Mth")
With qdf
    qdf.SQL = sqlString
    
    .SQL = Replace(.SQL, "Period='May 2018'", "Period='Jun 2018'")
    ' Code to do stuff with SQL-string/query
    ' .SQL = qdfOLD ' Reset SQL to old setting
    qdfOLD = .SQL
      
    ' DoCmd.RunSQL (Replace("Period='May 2018'", "Period='Jun 2018'"))
End With
Set qdf = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to pass parameters programmatically in a Microsoft Access update query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568461/is-it-possible-to-pass-parameters-programmatically-in-a-microsoft-access-update)

Comment: We can see the SQL string. Please show us the `sqlString`

Answer (score 0):

Your code sets the SQL string of the query to a string from a variable `sqlString` (where does it come from?), then replaces "Period='May 2018'" by "Period='Jun 2018'" in the SQL of the query, then saves the final SQL in a variable `qdfOld` (which isn't used and which is a string variable, so the prefix `qdf` is misleading). The string you are trying to find and replace is not contained in your query, because in the query, `Query1.Period` is enclosed in brackets.

Supposed that the variable `sqlString` contains the original query string, you most likely wanted to do something like this:

```
Private Sub newChangePeriodCriteria_Click()

    With CurrentDb
        With .QueryDefs("Query1_Mth")
            .SQL = Replace(sqlString, "(Query1.Period)='May 2018'", "(Query1.Period)='Jun 2018'")
            .Close
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

This is quite unusual, please take a look at *query parameters* (and the link that @ahleedawg provided).

**Added:**

Instead of opening the *query* in datasheet view, you can open a *form* in datasheet view. This will allow you to pass a `WHERE` clause.

Create a form ("PeriodsForm") based on the query `Query1` and use something like the following code to open it:

```
Sub OpenPeriodForm()

    DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="PeriodsForm", View:=acFormDS, WhereCondition:="Period='Jul 2018'"

End Sub
```

Comment: How can i change Period parameter  'Jul 2018' in VBA  code as follows             '**Private Sub PeriodChange_Click()
Dim db As dao.Database
Dim qdef As dao.QueryDef
Dim strSQL As String
Dim StrMth As String

Set db = CurrentDb
strSQL = "SELECT Query_Table_Period.Period FROM Query_Table_Period WHERE (Query_Table_Period.Period)= 'Jul 2018' "
Set qdef = db.QueryDefs("Period")
qdef.SQL = strSQL
qdef.Close
Set qdef = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
'DoCmd.OpenQuery "Period", acViewNormal
   
End Sub**'

Comment: Why would you open a query? Open a form instead. I'll add an example to my answer.

Comment: The problem arises that if I try to execute a query with criteria to a form control, it always result in an error ** “Too Few Parameters“** when trying run VBA to print report/export to PDF. It works fine if I do not execute query with criteria to a form Control. so I am looking for solution to change only  Period parameter criteria through VBA in the SQL part in  VBA code.

Comment: The problem is that you add more and more details after each comment you got. Aside from that I can't see anything useful in exporting a query result or datasheet to a PDF: Why don't you export the filtered form? If you insist to change the query, check my first code sample.